# Python: Get size of some files with special character name like：Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.pem

Tags: python, operating-system, special-characters

**Target:** I want to get the size of some files which have special characters in their name. Example: `Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.pem`.

**Code:**

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
        os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name))
```

---

**Error traceback:**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/xixc/workspace/sraf_qa_tools/test.py", line 16, in  os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name)) File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize return os.stat(filename).st_size WindowsError: [Error 123] : 'E:\SDK\K?k_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa?lay?c?s?_-_S\xa8\xb9r\xa8\‌​xb9m_3.pem'.

**Result:** `E:\SDK\K?k_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa?lay?c?s?_-_S��r��m_3.pem`.

It looks like Python can't get the special name, so **os.path.getsize**  can't find the files.

**Question:** How could I deal with the special name files?
I think I should do something with the **name** in my code.

Comment: What is there error you are seeing, paste in the traceback. I cannot replicate your issue. The `print` may not show the right characters but that is an encoding issue and shouldn't stop you from `stat`ing the file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xixc/workspace/sraf_qa_tools/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 123] : 'E:\\SDK\\K?k_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa?lay?c?s?_-_S\xa8\xb9r\xa8\xb9m_3.pem'

Comment: Try `os.walk(unicode(path))`, seems in Windows you need explicitly use `unicode` for it walk unicode filenames.